# Package 'Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.6.27428.2027,chip=x64' failed to install

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've installed VS2017 Community edition in Windows Server 2012 R2. I got the following error. My Server[Windows Server 2012 R2] got all the [Pre-Requisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs) installed. Could someone suggest on this.

```
Package 'Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.6.27428.2027,chip=x64' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1392
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.6.27428.2027,chip=x64\dotnet-sdk-2.1.104-win-x64.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community" /log "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180420124701_109_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log" /quiet /norestart
        Return code: 1392
        Return code details: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
    Log
        C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180420124701_109_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log
Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.6.27406.0)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.6.27309.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.6.27406.0)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.6.27406.0)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.6.27406.0)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.6.27428.2037)
    Impacted components
        .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK,version=15.6.27406.0)
        .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentTools,version=15.6.27421.1)
        .NET Core 2.0 development tools (Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.6.27406.0)
        .NET Native and .NET Standard (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard,version=15.6.27421.1)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.6.27323.2)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26504.0)
        Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.6.27406.0)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Cloud tools for web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools,version=15.6.27323.2)
        Container development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.6.27309.0)
```

Comment: Note the /log option passed to the installer.  So look at C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180420124701_109_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log for a more detailed error message.

Comment: "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable." run **chkdsk** to see if the file system is corrupted.

Comment: No luck..yet :-(